# Exception error : Unable to send data to service in Magento SaaSCommon module Magento 2.4.5 EE

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, exception, magento2.4.5, saas

Hi I keep getting this error in exception.log, but the site functions properly (Magento 2.4.5 EE), not sure what is causing this. Any Idea ?

```
[2023-07-24T23:58:06.458525+00:00] report.ERROR: Unable to send data to service {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\SaaSCommon\\Model\\Exception\\UnableSendData(code: 0): Unable to send data to service at /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.domainurl.com/___deploy/releases/20230717064305/vendor/magento/module-saas-common/Model/Http/Command/SubmitFeed.php:144)"} []
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a feature in Enterprise edition for using Saas (Software as a Service) features as Adobe Sensei for an example.

And the catalog sync process runs hourly to allow Commerce services to use catalog data. Catalog sync exports product data from the Commerce server to Commerce services on an ongoing basis to keep the services up to date. To use the Catalog Sync dashboard or the command-line interface, you must have an API key and a SaaS data space configured.
And this error is being thrown on your system because the API keys are not configured.
If you are not using these services you may disable the module to avoid printing these error.

Please refer to : https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-merchant-services/user-guides/data-services/catalog-sync.html
Or in turn if you wish to subscribe to any of these services, please refer to : https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-merchant-services/user-guides/integration-services/saas.html?lang=en